# Import a NPM module with a Nuxt Application in it

Tags: npm, nuxt.js, npm-install, server-side-rendering, generate

I would like to develop an NPM module that the user can import in his project.
The module contain a full administration panel created with [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/).
I don't want the user know anything about Nuxt, he just need to run a command like:

```sh
myppcommand start
```

and the application starts a server that is running the administration panel.

So my idea is to develop the NPM module with Nuxt. Generate all the static file inside `./dist` folder and then `myappcommand start` will serve the app from `node_modules`.

```js
// NPM Package myapp
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
    components: [
        {
            path: '~/components/',
            extensions: ['vue']
        }
    ],
    buildDir: './.nuxt',
    srcDir: './src/',
    target: 'static',
    ssr: false,
    generate: {
        dir: './dist/'
    }
};
```

```sh
// NPM Package myapp
npx nuxt generate
```

The command will generate all files in `./dist` folder.

```sh
// User repo
npm install myapp
```

This will install `myapp` inside `./node_modules`.

```sh
// User repo
cd node_modules/myapp/ && npx nuxt start -c nuxt.config.js
```

This will start the server and serve the app.

But is this the best way possible? It seems a bit hacky to me, to go inside `node_modules`, does somebody know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by declaring that your package has an executable file which starts Nuxt, in the [`bin` property of package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin).

Firstly, create an executable script to start the app:

**bin/start.js**

```js
    #!/usr/bin/env node

    // Based on node_modules/.bin/nuxt

    global.__NUXT_PATHS__ = (global.__NUXT_PATHS__ || []).concat(__dirname)
    
    require('@nuxt/cli').run(['start'])
      .catch((error) => {
        require('consola').fatal(error)
        process.exit(2)
      })
```

You can verify that this starts the app by running `./bin/start.js` (provided you have made the file executable), or `node ./bin/start.js`.

Then, declare that your package should install this as a script when installed as a dependency:

**package.json**

```json
    {
      "bin": {
        "myapp": "bin/start.js"
      }
    }
```

When your package has been installed with `npm install myapp`, then `node_modules/.bin/myapp` will link to `node_modules/myapp/bin/start.js` and the user will be able to run it with `npx myapp`.